# Kernel driver integrity check at runtime

Tags: c, kernel, runtime

I managed to do objcopy to view and extract the .rodata segment contents as references for immutable integrity check, however, I realized that kernel drivers are not able to read files. In that sense, how may we code the driver determine it’s own integrity at runtime?

Some sample code to make some illustrations would be good.

Comment: Why should kernel drivers not be able to read files.

Comment: I read about this: http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8110

Comment: If you're trying to read a file from within the kernel, you've definitely zigged somewhere you probably needed to zag, @Devolus there be dragons. _Without_ module signing, this becomes a very interesting problem, I'm going to chew on it a bit.

Comment: :D ... this is indeed a paradox. In fact, reading the kernel driver in some ways is frowned upon as indicated by the given url above. I am hoping for a safer way.

Comment: Note: As we develop towards the answers. I will +1 for any comments because I can only give 1 person the bounty for the final solution. However, +1 gradually may even exceed the bounty. Frankly speaking, if I have more points, I would like to give more away.

Answer (score 5):

You can verify the integrity of kernel modules at runtime using cryptographically signed modules.

Start with [this Unix and Linux Stack Exchange answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74022/sign-a-module-after-kernel-compilation).

[Here](https://lwn.net/Articles/470906/) is an update from Jake Edge regarding the status of crypto signing in the mainline kernel as of 2011. The patches were eventually migrated to the [mainline in 3.7](http://lwn.net/Articles/525592/).

Module signature is an configuration option in the recent kernels. You can set it when configuring the kernel with `menuconfig`: "Enable loadable module support"->"Module signature verification".

Comment: I have added a +1 for your answer, however, I am trying to do it by c code. Which means, upon loading, it reads itself and calculate it's integrity on-the-fly. Is there a way?

Comment: @UrsaMajor: The module reads its own file? It can do it and calculate a hash but that's not a good basis for trust. Better that the kernel tests the hash against it's own compiled-in signature cache. I recommend that you read the kernel code that does the signature verification in `kernel/module_signing.c`.

Comment: Is there a sample code on how to use

kernel/module_signing.c?

Comment: Read http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/servers-storage-admin/signed-kernel-modules-1891111.html, and https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dhowells/linux-modsign/+/modsign-rusty/Documentation/module-signing.txt, compile your own kernel with CONFIG_MODULE_SIG and sign some module to test it.

Comment: @UrsaMajor: "Which means, upon loading, it reads itself" - that'll not work. By the time your module's code starts to run, it'll not have any access to the source where it came from. All it can check is the running kernel code with the module code already linked in, and I doubt that you'd be able to do any sane integrity check there.

Comment: @LaszloValko, I understand the circular logic flaw there. It's just a mitigation, not full-proof. If it is mere OS app, it's easier, I can do objcopy of a loaded copy and do verification with another stored value. This has been done before, but for kernel, it can't read file or do system() to objcopy the loaded (insmod) copy for that case. BTW, +1 for all your comments. :)

Comment: @UrsaMajor: the file to be loaded is available for checking only in the code which does the actual loading. You may replace the module-loading code in the kernel, but why bothering, when this (module signing) has already been implemented...

Comment: It is some strange requirement under the circumstances that there is no module signing.

Comment: @UrsaMajor without signing, I can't think of any way to pull this off without help from userspace, but that's not _nearly_ as strong - would you want something along those lines? I might be able to come up with something.

Comment: yes, it is a paradox, I understand. This requirement is really strange, but it comes under taxing constraints. There is no help from the userspace. It has to be self-sufficient. I am even working out the formal methods to see if there is anyway to prove this before the code. However, as a start, I am just trying to find codes to determine the memory address where the kernel module is residing, and to read the contents of the kernel module itself.

For the time being, +1 for you @TimPost. I really appreciate this, Tim. I am hoping to find the code blocks to solve this puzzle.

Comment: A module checking its own integrity sounds like a bullet point in FIPS 140-2. It's a bureaucratic requirement inherited from the time when things were done in hardware, and hardware requires a self-check — in software it often doesn't make any sense. @UrsaMajor It can be done with a small patch to the module loading function. I think there's even GPL code to do that somewhere on the web (but you may have to look hard).

Comment: I did a search, it seems to be module_signing.c, but I am unsure how to use it or incorporate it. I am not allowed to change the base kernel, only the loadable modules.

+1 --> Gilles.

Comment: @JonathanBen-Avraham, 
where is the CONFIG_MODULE_SIG set for android kernel?

Comment: @UrsaMajor: Since Linux kernel 3.3, corresponding to Jelly Bean, Android uses mainline Linux kernels. In the kernel source do: make menuconfig, then follow menu path: "Enable loadable module support"->"Module signature verification". HTH.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this another way.

Kernel device drivers can only be loaded by root.  Therefore the binary image may be placed somewhere that only root can access.  When installed, both the driver and a separate checker application may be placed in this directory.  At that point the code on disk cannot change (excepting hardware errors and malware) unless it is done by root.

If someone has the root password, then they can do anything, so make sure your system is locked down properly and the whole integrity issue goes away.

You could even run the CRC checker program every boot to verify the contents of the driver file (although the driver will already have been loaded), a message could be logged as to the integrity of the driver.

Comment: can you provide some codes / commands to illustrate what you do - step-by-step?
There may be be requirement for some codes as it may be done on-the-fly without human intervention.

+1 for you, @Neil.

Comment: @UrsaMajor Not sure what you are asking for here.  You must already know how to load a driver? Then in some part of the start up sequence (init.d?) you run your checker program which will verify the integrity of the driver and write any problems to the syslog, send an email or whatever you require.

Comment: we can't do that during runtime, where human intervention is not allowed. 

+1 for your warm help, Neil.

Comment: What do you intend to do when the 'invalid' driver is detected?  Email someone? Display onscreen?  Shut-down?  All of these things can be done via the 'checker' program.  In fact, the 'checker' program could be the one to load the driver if it was determined to be ok.

Comment: The paradox is that the 'checker' program is required to be 'self-contained', ie. it checks itself before allow further access to do the run. I know it sounds unreasonable, but that's the situation. :(

It will just return a failed status, and whatever, the users wish to use it for is up to them.

Comment: So the user (init.d or whatever) will run the checker, which if everything is ok will system("lmmod driver"), or return an error.  The driver could return an error if the parent isn't the checker, so it couldn't be loaded manually.  If you really really want to go to the effort of a single package, the driver could be extracted from the checker at runtime and the driver file could be in RAMDISK or marked at temporary, so it's not physically stored anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately, human intervention is not possible, it has to be automated at boot time and runtime. Hence, the code must be contained in the module itself. The question is - how?

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood my use of user.  I meant the boot script (init.d or init.rc or whatever it is on your system) will run the checker, the checker will verify integrity and then load the driver.

Comment: It has to be C program at runtime if possible. I can't touch the boot, but I will suggest, not sure if the requirement may allow. 

I tried 
<pre>
#include <linux/jiffies.h>

    printk(KERN_INFO "[%s] module loaded.\n", __this_module.name);
    printk("[%s] current jiffies: %lu.\n", __this_module.name, jiffies);

</pre>
but it is not giving the memory location.

Comment: Forgive me if this is unhelpful, but to anyone with a reasonable knowledge of Linux and programming, what I'm suggesting is pretty basic stuff. If you struggle to comprehend what I'm saying, I feel you would not be able to implement these suggestions anyway.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to use a different piece of software to do the checking. A driver that had been tampered with maliciously would probably run silent, so if you expect the check to be done exclusively inside each driver you will have no way of telling a rogue driver from one that passed its internal check.

To avoid this, better have a master supervision demon that have no contact with the outside world and whose job is solely to check all the drivers. If you're still concerned the master checker could be hijacked, make that 3 paranoid androids watching each other's integrity.

The drivers would have an interface to exchange periodic handshakes with the supervision software, or they could expose a part of their memory to the supervisors (read only access), that could then perform paranoid checks in the background without the drivers even neededing to waste time in a communication protocol.

From what I understand of your question, you plan on using static data as a means of checking integrity. In that scenario, the master checkers would have a copy of the said .rodata and a pointer to the very driver memory, and perform periodic CRC or whatever check code computation to make sure the driver did not get tampered with.

EDIT: I'm anything but a linux driver savvy, but the pseudo-code would look like this:

1) preliminary work when a driver is (re)built

save the driver's relevant check data (contents of the.rodata for instance) in a specific location accessable only by the supervisor

2) inside each driver

communicate once at load time with the supervisor to provide a user space read-only pointer to the .rodata

3) supervisor

continuously read each driver's .rodata (once every few seconds) and match them against the corresponding file.

A simple CRC could be enough instead of the whole .rodata copy, but using the .rodata as a whole would allow to change the integrity check mechanism without having to touch the existing drivers.

EDIT (bis):

#### .rodata address and size

getting the address of the .rodata can be done with a dirty trick as simple as defining a static variable at the start of the area. I am no ELF expert but I guess some compiler and linker directives should do the trick:

- define a custom section through whatever pragma the compiler offers, or use assembly language for that if no C/C++ alternative are available
- put somme dummy variable in that section (a simple symbol if you use assembly will do the trick without adding a single useless byte to the file)
- tell the linker to order the sections so that our dummy gets located just before .rodata

by getting the address of this dummy at runtime, we have the start address of .rodata as loaded in the driver execution context.

The same trick can be used with another dummy located just after `.rodata` to get the size of the section.
This will allow to determine the size of the user-space mapped area that will be made available to the supervisor.

#### Mapping driver .rodata into supervisor's address space

By using [mmap](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mmap), you can map some part of the driver's memory into user space.

See an example [here](http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~ghose/CS529/sharedmemmap.htm)

Once the mapping is defined, you can pass it to the supervisor with an IOCTL.

If you want yet an added layer of security, the IOCTL can include a password exchange so that a malicious software cannot get easy read access to the .rodata (though I wonder how such a software could be running in the middle of your kernel without you explicitely putting it there).

#### reading files from kernel drivers

The trick here is that the drivers themselves will never need to read a file.

- the .rodata contents will be extracted at compile/link time from the driver's ELF file
- that file will only be read by the supervisor (a mere user-level program).

Comment: How do we determine the memory address of the .rodata after loading? We may not know where it is loaded to. I also have issues with kernel drivers reading files. 

Ref:
linuxjournal.com/article/8110 

* ps. Could you add to the comments so that I can do a +1 for you?

Comment: @UrsaMajor see my edit. Using a tiny assembly source (identical for each driver) and adding a map directive to the linker should be enough to do the trick, I think.

Comment: @kuroineko  Are you suggesting that the driver gives it's virtual memory map to another process that is running in user space?  Using IOCTL or similar? Yes you can do that, but I don't think the user-space app can actually see the driver's address space.  E.g. IN memory, Process1 @ 0x12345678 is not physically the same memory byte as Process2 @ 0x12345678.

Comment: @Neil you can map kernel space into user space, by defining a memory mapped zone that points to the same physical address. Just like a driver sharing a buffer with some application-level process. Again I'm no Linux driver expert, but the mechanism is bound to be available in any driver architecture. Basically you get the user-space reference through an IOCTL, compute the accessable window, define a user space mapped pointer and return it to the application.

Comment: Thank you, friends. You are giving me some good ideas to think about. However, it is not clear. A small program to demo it may help.

In any case, I have to +1 for all of you. ;)